# Change led blinking interval with button input in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, led

I want to change the blinking time of LED with every button press.
The code i written in python do not respond to button input clicks. what chages does it need?**looks like callback isnt working**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

inbutton = 13
outpin = 7
z = 1


def init():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(outpin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(inbutton, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    global z
    z = 1


def zest():
    global z
    if z == 1:
        z = 2
        while z == 2:
            GPIO.output(outpin, 1)
            print("led on")
            sleep(1)

            GPIO.output(outpin, 0)
            print("led off")
            sleep(1)

    elif z == 2:
        z = 1
        while z == 1:
            GPIO.output(outpin, 1)
            print("led on")
            sleep(2)

            GPIO.output(outpin, 0)
            print("led off")
            sleep(2)


def loop():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(inbutton, GPIO.FALLING, callback=zest(), bouncetime=1000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
    try:
        while True:
            loop()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.output(outpin, 0)
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

On running LED blinks with 1second interval. but dont respond to button click.experts out there please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(inbutton, GPIO.FALLING, callback=zest(), bouncetime=1000)
```

to this:

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(inbutton, GPIO.FALLING, callback=zest, bouncetime=1000)
```

As you have it, the callback is called once when registering it and registered callback is saved as `None` since that is what was returned by `zest()`.

The callback also needs to accept a single argument: `channel`. So change your function definition to:

```
def zest(channel):
```

Comment: Made this change and i ran code. with each click of button following error is displayed as output - TypeError: zest() takes no arguments (1 given).

Comment: @sas I've never used the `RPi` module before. Apparently, `add_event_detect` expects a callback that takes one argument: `channel`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: By using self argument i.e. def zest(self) and using callback=zest, above mentioned error is eliminated. But still not able to change blink interval with each button press.